# Equilibrium between a system and a heat reservoir

Tags: statistical-mechanics

In Pathria's Statistical Mechanics, Section 3.1, the expression for the probability, $P_r$ of finding a system characterized by the energy value $E_R$ in a reservoir is derived. The derivation goes as follows:

> We consider the given system $A$, immersed in a very large heat reservoir $A'$ [...] On attaining a state of mutual equilibrium, the system and the reservoir would have a *common* temperature, *say* $T$. Their energies, however, would be variable and, in principle, could have, at any time *t,* values lying anywhere between $0$ and $E^{(0)},$ where $E^{(0)}$ denotes the energy of the composite system [...]
> $$E_r + E'_r=E^{(0)}=\rm const.$$
> ... Let the number of these states be denoted by $\Omega'(E'_r)$ [...]
> $$P_r \propto \Omega'(E'_r) \equiv  \Omega'(E^{(0)} -E_r).$$
> [...] we may carry out an expansion [...] around $E_r =0.$ However, for reasons of convergence, it is essential to effect the expansion of the logarithm instead:
> $$\ln \Omega'(E'_r) = \ln \Omega'(E^{(0)}) + \left(\frac{\partial \ln \Omega'}{\partial E'} \right)_{E'=E^{(0)}}(E'_r - E^{(0)}) + ...$$
> $$\approx const - \beta'E_r,$$
> [...] in equilibrium, $\beta' = \beta = 1/kT.$$
> [...]
> $$P_r \propto \exp(-\beta E_r)$$

I have a few questions here:

1. For many systems, is it not the case that the temperature can be expressed as a function of the energy? An ideal gas is one such example. In that case, supposing I had an ideal gas inside a reservoir, which was free to exchange energy, but held at fixed particle number and volume, how could it be possible for it to be at a common temperature, but still take on any energy value?
2. Why is it essential to effect the expansion of the logarithm instead? What is the justification for this?
3. (Edit:) Why is the relevant probability taken to be
   $$P_r \propto \Omega' (E'_r)$$
   rather than
   $$P_r \propto \Omega' (E'_r) \cdot \Omega(E_r)?$$
   Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For many systems, is it not the case that the temperature can be
> expressed as a function of the energy? An ideal gas is one such
> example.

What you're referring is the relationship between the internal energy and temperature. The internal energy is a thermodynamic quantity of the system which is calculated as an ensemble average from Statistical Mechanics. What Pathria here refers to here is not the ensemble average energy, it is simply the energy of the system at any instant in time. Ensemble averaged energy (or internal energy) would be equivalent to time-averaged energy, according to ergodic hypothesis. Even in the case of ideal gas, the internal energy is related to the temperature as $U \propto k_B T$, not the instantaneous energy.

> In that case, supposing I had an ideal gas inside a reservoir, which
> was free to exchange energy, but held at fixed particle number and
> volume, how could it be possible for it to be at a common temperature,
> but still take on any energy value?

This is precisely the framework of canonical ensemble in statistical  mechanics. The system is free to exchange energy and as a result a thermal equilibrium of common temperature is attained between the reservoir and system. To physically understand this, imagine the system on an average has energy $U$, but the system's energy changes instantaneously, fluctuating around the value $U$. While the energy fluctuates around $U$, the temeprature $T$ of the system and reservoir remain constant, such that the temperature is directly related to the average energy $U$.

> Why is it essential to effect the expansion of the logarithm instead? What is the justification for this?

$\Omega(E)$ scales as the density of states of the system, which grows as $E^N$, where $N$ is the number of particles in the system. Realistically speaking, this is a extremely sharply rising function as $N$ ~ $10^{23}$. Therefore taking logarithmic expansion gives a much better approximation.

Comment: Thanks, please see my edit too.

Comment: @Jbag1212 May I know what is the difference between $\Omega$ and $\Omega'$?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I forgot that wasn’t included in the OP. The $’$s in general refer to the reservoir, and unprimed is the system in equilibrium with the reservoir.

Comment: Nevermind, I was just misreading. I thought they were asserting $P_S \propto \Omega_S$, but they were really asserting $P_S \propto \Omega_R$ for a particular microstate.

Comment: Is it more accurate to say that $\Omega(E)$ scales as $\exp(-\beta E)$? Then $d \ln \Omega / d E = \beta$ for some constant $\beta.$ The conclusion reached that $P_r \propto \Omega \propto \exp(-\beta E)$ is equivalent to assuming that the expansion of the logarithm is a "good" expansion. But assuming that $\Omega(E) \propto E^N$ implies that $P_r \propto \exp(N \ln(E))$. Asserting that $P_r \propto \exp( E \cdot (n \ln(E)/E)$ where $\beta = n \ln(E)/E$ seems strange.

Comment: @Jbag1212 I am sorry, but I don't clearly understand your concern. Here, $\Omega(E)$ concerns the total number of microstates for a given macrostate of energy $E$. One can explicity calculate this value in microcanonical framework and obtain that $\Omega(E) \sim E^N$. Would you mind clarifying your question again?

Comment: @Jbag1212 Have you stumbled upon this notes (https://itp.uni-frankfurt.de/~gros/Vorlesungen/TD/9_Canonical_ensemble.pdf), they present a fairly lucid explanation of canonical ensemble

Comment: "One can explicitly calculate this value in microcanonical framework" - the reservoir here is supposed to be completely general. Therefore, I do not see how you can say that its value can be explicitly calculated. My concern is that if $\Omega(E) \sim E^N$ then it does not also seem like $\Omega(E) \sim \exp(\beta E).$ $E^N$ and $e^{(cE)}$ are differently behaving functions.